# Numerical integration over non-uniform Grids

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function which I want to integrate. I have two numpy arrays, one with the `x`-values and one with the function `f(x)`. I am looking for a function `F(x)` which is the antiderivative of `f(x)`, defined on the same grid `x`. This grid `x` is *non-uniform*.

Is there some numpy or scipy function giving me the array `F(x)`?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I thought this would be it, but now I think it's not. Maybe I'm missing something: The first section (integrating function object) is not applicable, as I do not have a callable. The second section (integrating fixed samples) is not what I want, since it doesn't return an array. The ODE solver requires a callable again, doesn't it?

Comment: You can make your own callable.  Look at Python's `itemgetter` for inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely looking for [scipy.integrate.cumtrapz](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html).